# if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) in AJAX not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying ajax on my page. But it is not working as `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)` is always false. I have alerted the values of `xmlhttp.readyState` and `xmlhttp.status`. There values are always 1 and 0 respectively for `xmlhttp.open` event and 4 & 0 respectively for `xmlhttp.close` event.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function captcha_check()
{
    var code = document.getElementById("captcha").value;
    var url = "http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php?img='.$captcha_name.'.jpgx&ans="+code;
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        alert(xmlhttp.readyState + " " + xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("captcha_error").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          return false;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","captcha_check.php?img=abc.jpg&ans="+code,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

What the issue may be and how can I solve it and make the AJAX functioning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the Network tab in developer tools say?

Comment: Btw why not to just `$.get()` it?

Comment: use `$.ajax` to save time...

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The correct order of calls is:

- `new XMLHttpRequest`
- `xhr.open()`
- `xhr.onreadystatechange = ...`
- `xhr.send()`

In some browsers, calling `.open` clears any event handlers on it. This allows for clean re-use of the same XHR object, which is supposedly more memory-efficient (but that really doesn't matter if you code properly to let the GC do its job)

So, simply put the `.open` call before the `onreadystatechange` assignment and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your code is working perfectly, as mentioned in the comments, since your already included jQuery try:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function captcha_check() {
  var code = document.getElementById("captcha").value;
  var url = "http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php?img='.$captcha_name.'.jpgx&ans="+code;
  jQuery.get("captcha_check.php?img=abc.jpg&ans="+code", function(data) {
    alert("Load was performed.");
    console.log(data);
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you are making an AJAX request from a page loaded in the browser directly from the file system, rather than from a Web Server. Since you are issuing a GET request, browser caching might be an issue as well. Try appending a timestamp to the URL each time so the URL is unique:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "captcha_check.php?img=abc.jpg&ans=" + code
    + "&__cachebuster__=" + new Date().getTime());
```

Secondly, you need to escape the `code` variable to make it safe for a query string:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "captcha_check.php?img=abc.jpg&ans=" + escape(code)
    + "&__cachebuster__=" + new Date().getTime());
```

Lastly, please check for any occurences of `$_POST` in your captcha_check.php file, as this would indicate you should be issuing a POST request, not a GET request.

If:

1. You are loading a page in the browser directly from the file system, AJAX requests will fail
2. You enter non query string safe characters for the `code`, then you end up with an invalid URL, and AJAX requests will fail
3. The `captcha_check.php` file requires a POST request and you issue a GET request, the AJAX request will fail.

Answer (score 0):

xmlhttp.open("GET","captcha_check.php?img=abc.jpg&ans="+code,true);

Please check file path, maybe its wrong path.